# React Native I can not run iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

I tried the below and I got error message

```
(react-native init ReactProject5)
```

then the application completely created

```
( ,,,-MacBook-ReactProject5 ,,,$ react-native run-ios
```

then I got  below error

```
Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier 
build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactProject5.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding from XCode.

Comment: is this xcode 9?